# How to move the “Recently Viewed Products” widget in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I have added the 'Recently viewed products' widget on the product view page(2 columns left). Currently, it's showing below the product info details section. But I want it full width. So I want to move this widget into the main content area or above the footer.
so how to move this section? If anyone knows please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/widget.xml you see the containers section. This means the recently viewed products can only be placed in the sidebar main, content and sidebar additional containers.

```
    <widget id="catalog_recently_viewed" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed"
        placeholder_image="Magento_Catalog::images/product_widget_viewed.png">
    <label translate="true">Recently Viewed Products</label>
    <description translate="true">List of Products Recently Viewed by Visitor</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="uiComponent" xsi:type="text" required="false" visible="false">
            <label translate="true">UI Component</label>
            <value>widget_recently_viewed</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="page_size" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Number of Products to display</label>
            <value>5</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="show_attributes" xsi:type="multiselect" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Product attributes to show</label>
            <options>
                <option name="name" value="name">
                    <label translate="true">Name</label>
                </option>
                <option name="image" value="image">
                    <label translate="true">Image</label>
                </option>
                <option name="price" value="price">
                    <label translate="true">Price</label>
                </option>
                <option name="learn_more" value="learn_more">
                    <label translate="true">Learn More Link</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="show_buttons" xsi:type="multiselect" required="true" visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Buttons to show</label>
            <options>
                <option name="add_to_cart" value="add_to_cart">
                    <label translate="true">Add to Cart</label>
                </option>
                <option name="add_to_compare" value="add_to_compare">
                    <label translate="true">Add to Compare</label>
                </option>
                <option name="add_to_wishlist" value="add_to_wishlist">
                    <label translate="true">Add to Wishlist</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="template" xsi:type="select" required="true" visible="true">
            <label>Template</label>
            <options>
                <option name="grid" value="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" selected="true">
                    <label translate="true">Viewed Products Grid Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="list" value="product/widget/viewed/list.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">Viewed Products List Template</label>
                </option>
                <option name="sidebar" value="product/widget/viewed/sidebar.phtml">
                    <label translate="true">Viewed Products Sidebar Template</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
    <containers>
        <container name="sidebar.main">
            <template name="default" value="sidebar" />
        </container>
        <container name="content">
            <template name="grid" value="grid" />
            <template name="list" value="list" />
        </container>
        <container name="sidebar.additional">
            <template name="default" value="sidebar" />
        </container>
    </containers>
</widget>
```

You can try adding an etc/widget.xml in a custom module and add containers for the recently viewed widget in the container node. For example in page.top (After Page Header).

```
 <container name="page.top">
     <template name="grid" value="grid" />
     <template name="list" value="list" />
 </container>
```

In [Extending a Magento widget layout within a theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307564/extending-a-magento-widget-layout-within-a-theme) is explained how to extend a widget in the widget xml.